# What is the purpose of Encapsulation? Does it provide a security layer?

Tags: java, c#, oop

As much as I have studied about encapsulation it is about hiding data to prevent from manipulation. For that we declare the private variables so that couldn't be accessible from out of class. But we can implement or access them out of class using setter getter method. So if we have to implement it using setter getter method than any other person can implement it using setter getter method. . So how we are safe from manipulation??

Comment: One advantage of a setter is that you can check the value before setting. Imagine a class car that contains a field speed. You don't want the car driving more than 120 km/h, so you can check in the setter method if the value is greater than 120.

Comment: Sure - if you have a setter that lets a caller set any value they want at any time they want, it scarcely amounts to encapsulation.  But not every getter needs a (public) setter, and not every public setter needs to blindly execute an assignment. A better-written setter rejects invalid values and actions.

Comment: It isn't really about security. Rather it is to limit the interactions with your object to something where the side effects of its mutations can be controlled. For example, my class might have a timeout property, but I might to prevent it being set to a value outside a predetermined range. But yes, people who have access to your source code can change it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20753372/when-should-encapsulation-be-used

Answer (score 3):

Encapsulation isn't a security measure in that it prevents people from messing with your code. It's a security measure in the sense that people can't go directly in and change variables without going through your proper channels. Consider the following psuedocode.

```
class ProgressBar {
    public int maximum;
    public int current;
}
```

vs

```
class ProgressBar {
    private int maximum;
    private int current;

    ...
    public set_current(int amount) {
        if (amount <= this.maximum) this.current = amount;
    }
}
```

In the top example, users could go in and mess with current and break the
progress bar. In the bottom example, your setter protects from that.

Comment: "Security" is probably the wrong word, at least in English.  "Constraint" is the word I hear most often.  Constraints must be placed on data to make sure the data is valid.  The example of 120 km/hr limit on car speed is an example of a constraint.  Allowing direct access of a field doesn't allow your class to place any constraints on its own fields.

Answer (score 1):

You need to look at this way,

`your code` <------ `client code`

Client code will be trying to access your code. With `Encapsulation`, your data will be safe from manipulation that can be done by the client code. It will help in specifying the accessibility limit.

To give an Example,

You are building a game and you wouldn't want someone to increase the health of your character (manipulate the fixed data)

```
public class GameCharacter {

public int Health{ get; } 

public GameCharacter ()
{
    Health = 100;
}

}
```

No one can change the Health!

Comment: I got the idea but nobody can change health without set(). With set() it not secure anymore cuz of anyone can access. How encapsulation solve this problem ?

Comment: @TuLeAnh yes anyone can access set(). But you can have logic inside the set() so no one is able to put invalid data.

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of Encapsulation is two-fold:

1. Bundling related functionality together;
2. Controlling the access to fields and methods which participate in providing the functionality.

---

The goal of getters and setters is to ensure that actors outside the code (or class) have only one point of interaction with your fields, thus maintaining the [invariants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariant_(mathematics)#Invariants_in_computer_science). This helps in:

> 1. Preventing modification of values in an illegal/unacceptable manner that can break the functionality.

Ex: Two external actors trying to modify your account balance at the same time;

> 2. Localizing an aspect of code that may change in future.

Ex: Easily allowing you to change the type of a status variable from boolean to enum in future because it is always accessed from getter in the class;

> 3. Implement business rules, if any, that are need to be exercised when changes are made to your fields.

Ex: Not allowing the Engine class to modify and set the speed of your Car class to a negative value, just because the car is going in reverse.